# Metric on $M/G$ which makes $\pi: M\to M/G$ a Riemannian submersion

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $G$ be a Lie group acting isometrically, freely and properly on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and $\pi:M\to N:=M/G$ the natural projection. Show that there is a unique metric $h$ on $N$ which makes the projection $\pi:(M,g)\to (N,h)$ a Riemannian submersion.

For $x\in N$ and $p\in\pi^{-1}(x)$, we take the vertical/horizontal spaces $V_p:=\ker d\pi_p$ and $H_p:=V_p^\perp$, so that $T_pM=V_p\oplus H_p$. Since $d\pi_p$ is surjective, then $d\pi_p|_{H_p}:H_p\to T_{\pi(p)}N$ is bijective. For $v_1,v_2\in T_xN$, we define:
$$h_x(v_1,v_2)=g_p(d\pi|_{H_p}^{-1}v_1,d\pi|_{H_p}^{-1}v_2)$$
(in particular, this satisfies $|v|_g=|d\pi(v)|_h$)

I was able to prove $h_x$ doesn't depend on the choice of $p$ using the fact that $G$ acts isometrically. The uniqueness comes easy from the fact that another $h'$ would be such that $|v|_{h'}=|v|_h$ for all $v\in T_xN$, which is enough to conclude $h'=h$.

I'm having trouble to prove $h$ is smooth. I wish to argue that if $X,Y$ are a fields in $N$, we may find horizontal fields $X_H, Y_H$ in $M$ such that $d\pi(X_H)=X,d\pi(Y_H)=Y$, so $h(X,Y)=g(X_H,Y_H)$. I only need to show that such fields $X_H,Y_H$ exist (I believe they do), but I don't know how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y\in N$, and $x\in M$ such that $p(x)=y$. Let $U$ be an open subset containing $x$ whose adherence $V$ is compact. Since the action is proper, $Orb_x\cap V$ has a finite number of connected components. We can shrink $U$ such that $U$ contains a unique connected  component of $Orb_x\cap V$, $C$, let $T$ be a submanifold transverse to $C$, the restriction $p$ of $\pi$ to $T$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, for every $z\in T$, we can define $Y_H(z)=dp^{-1}_{\pi(z)}(X_H(\pi(z))$.

Comment: Tselmo, thanks for your answer! I've just had another idea, I'd like to know what you think: since $\pi$ is a submersion, we can find charts $(U,\phi)$ at $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ at $x$ such that $$\psi\circ \pi\circ \phi^{-1}:(x_1,...,x_m)\mapsto (x_1,...,x_n)$$
Therefore, $H_q=\text{span}\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_1}\right|_q,...,\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_m}\right|_q\right)$ for all $q\in U$. So if $X=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_i}$, we define $X_H:=\sum_{i=1}^m(f_i\circ\pi)\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i}$. Thoes this look correct?